# Extract data from respone Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, promise, response

I have 1 component and 1 service.

Component element :

```
...
constructor(private requestService : RequestService)
{

}
ngOnInit()
{
    this.a = this.requestService.send_request(urlWebAPI);
    console.log(this.a);
}
...
```

Service:

```
constructor(private http: Http) 
{
    this.http = http; 
    this.headers = new Headers
    ({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
}

send_request(additional_url: String) 
{       
    return this.http.post(this.url + additional_url, {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
private handleError(error: any) 
{
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

But this is what I get printed...How I can directly extract 'listaUniversita' array from this request?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
send_request(additional_url: String) 
{       
    return this.http.post(this.url + additional_url, {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data)                    //<----changed it
        .catch(this.handleError);
}


ngOnInit()
{
    this.requestService.send_request(urlWebAPI).then((result) => {  //<----changed it
       this.a=result;
    )};
}
```

Comment: Later when I print "a" it is still "Undefined"

Comment: Yes, I just had to change "data" field...ty!

Answer (score 2):

you can add new method call extractData to the service and it should be like this.

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.data || { };
}
```

and change the http call like this.

```
return this.http.post(this.url + additional_url, {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

reference https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

using this method you can minimize the code size else you have to hard code `response => response.json().data` this every http call.

Comment: The this.extractData method sometimes bugs and does not give the wished results. instead when hardcoding response => response.json().data it does give what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your ngOnInit get the returned promise as follows :

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.requestService.send_request(urlWebAPI).then((result) => { 
    console.log(result);
    )};
}
```

Console.log will display the contents returned from the server. i.e console.log(result.listaUniversita)